# Site that can store your videos and give you a .mp4 link

Tags: video, html5

I am making a site to share my videos. I don't want to embed YouTube videos or Dailymotion. I made my own advanced HTML5 video player. But the problem is that the HTML5 code should have a .mp4 link for the video, and my hosting only allow 2GB of data. Can I upload my videos to somewhere else and get an .mp4 link for it? I want the site to be good (not shutdown or remove my video after sometime). Thanks :)

Comment: @oliver-salzburg Can you please explain why this is off-topic and where can I post it? (In what StackExchange site?)

Comment: *Why* is explained in the message below your question. I don't think this kind of question is a good for any SE site. You could try [chat].

Comment: The site which can store something like this is your own site.  Just purchase more storage, or use cloud storage ( Amazon, Azure, Google, etc. ).  There is not current a Stackexchange website for service recomendations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One which comes to mind is [Streamable](https://streamable.com/) Where you can upload the video and you should get a link that you could embed or possibly get an mp4 link.

Comment: Oh okay thanks a lot :) Marked as good answer :) Do you know why I got 2 down votes? I think some people just down vote any question they can't answer. Or is their any problem with my question? Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm not too sure cyber, Someone usually gives an explanation as to what is wrong but it has not happened on this post

Comment: @CyberShadow - You were downvoted because your question wasn't on topic here at Superuser.  It also shows absolutely no research effort on your part.

Comment: @Ramhound How the hell can I show my effort? Post a video about me searching on Google and not finding an answer?

Comment: Thanks! This worked, at least for the time being. From the FAQs:

"How long are my videos stored?
Videos that are inactive for 3 months are deleted in order to make room for new content. For paid plans, videos are deleted only upon request."

https://support.streamable.com/frequently-asked-questions